# Compute (a) P(X = 2|Y = 3) and (b) P(Y = 3|X = 3) for the following joint distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I have some trouble understanding a question from my testbook. The question is as follows:
Compute (a) P(X = 2|Y = 3) and (b) P(Y = 3|X = 3) for the following
joint distribution:

```
Y X=1   2    3
1  0.2 0.15 0.05
2  0.10  0  0.10
3  0.05 0.15 0.20
```

I think I do not understand this, because my answers would be to easy. 
The answer of my first question is:
$$ a:P(X = 2|Y = 3) =  .15 $$

My Second answer:
$$ b: P(Y = 3|X = 3) = 1/5 $$

I know it is wrong, because my textbook has a different answer, but I have no idea what I do wrong.
They have the following answers:
$$ a: 1/6 $$
$$ b: 1/2 $$

Comment: For (a) you have $P(X=2 \text{ and }Y=3)=0.15$ from the table.  Try calculating $P(Y=3)$.  Then $P(X=2 \mid Y=3)= \frac{P(X=2 \text{ and }Y=3)}{P(Y=3)}$

Comment: Thank you for the help! I think that is the correct way to calculate it, but I still got a different answer. I got:
$$ P(Y=3)=0.05+0.15+0.20=.4 $$
$$ P(X=2∣Y=3)=.15/.4=3/8 $$
I hope that you could tell what I did wrong.

Comment: Your new calculation is what I would do